# Is there any way to enter and review formulae on computer?

Tags: self-learning

I was wondering if there was any website or software which would allow to enter all the formulae I'd like to study and then to review them by randomly picking some of them. A bit like chrome extensions which allow you to double click on foreign languages words to store them in a dictionary and then to study them later, but with maths.

Comment: You mean www.wolframalpha.com ?
Or you could just get software, like Python, Mathematica, Maple, Matlab

Comment: Well what I'd need is not to compute formulae, just to store them in a "list" which I could study whenever I want, either online or on a separated software. Do Python Mathlab and the others offer such feature ?

Comment: You can save whatever code you want as a file. You can make graphs of functions, calculate derivatives and anti-derivatives. I don't really get what you want, but there's nothing Python can't, and little the others can't in mathematics.

Comment: Yes well I'm not a native English speaker so I must say it's quite hard to explain but thanks for your suggestions, I'll check these and I believe there is a way to do what I'd like.